# Why TensorReduce not working here?

Tags: symbolic, linear-algebra, tensors

I would like to use `TensorReduce` to work on the tensor contraction $y_{ib}y_{ia}$ (where index $i$ is summed). However, `TensorReduce` does not bring the following `t1` and `t2` into a unique form:

```
$Assumptions = y ∈ Arrays[{d, d}];
t1 = TensorContract[TensorProduct[y, y], {{1, 3}}];
t2 = TensorTranspose[TensorContract[TensorProduct[y, y], {{1, 3}}], {2, 1}];
TensorReduce[t1]
TensorReduce[t2]

(* Output: *)
(* t1 -> TensorContract[y ⊗ y, {{1, 3}}] *)
(* t2 -> TensorTranspose[TensorContract[y ⊗ y, {{1, 3}}], {2, 1}] *)
```

Shouldn't they be brought into the same form? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbolic tensor analysis is new in version 9 and it is not yet fully implemented.

For example, *Mathematica* knows that `t1` and `t2` are symmetric

```
TensorSymmetry[t1]
TensorSymmetry[t2]
(* Symmetric[{1, 2}] *)
(* Symmetric[{1, 2}] *)
```

But it can't simplify transposition automatically. I think you can contact to the Wolfram support. Now you can use the following workaround:

```
transpose[t_, n_: {2, 1}] := Module[{t1}, 
  TensorReduce[Transpose[t1, n], 
    Assumptions -> {t1 ∈ Arrays[TensorDimensions[t], Complexes, TensorSymmetry[t]]}] /. 
   t1 -> t]

transpose[t1]
(* TensorContract[y\[TensorProduct]y, {{1, 3}}] *)
```

It is interesting that everything works fine for the contraction of the right indexes $y_{ai}y_{bi}$:

```
$Assumptions = y ∈ Arrays[{d, d}];
t1 = TensorContract[TensorProduct[y, y], {{2, 4}}];
t2 = TensorTranspose[
   TensorContract[TensorProduct[y, y], {{2, 4}}], {2, 1}];
TensorReduce[t1]
TensorReduce[t2]
(* TensorContract[y\[TensorProduct]y, {{2, 4}}] *)
(* TensorContract[y\[TensorProduct]y, {{2, 4}}] *)
```